# Warning when installing Tailwind in Django

Tags: python, django, tailwind-css

To have tailwind in my django project I'm trying to crete an output.css file using:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./static/src/input.css -o ./static/dist/output.css --watch
```

and I'm getting these warnings:

```
warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

If I get it correct the problem seems to be my  `tailwind.config.js`  and maybe I did not set the path correctly. This is my `tailwind.config.js`  file:

```
module.exports = {
 content: [
     './templates/**/*.html'
 ],
 theme: {
   extend: {},
 },
 plugins: [],
}
```

This is my django's project structure:

```
- website
   -- main
   -- app1
   -- static   
       --- src
       --- dist
       --- node_modules
       --- tailwind.config.js
   -- templates
       --- assets
           ---- base.html
       --- main
           ---- index.html
       --- app1
   -- website
       --- setting.py
```

this is my input.css file:

```
/* static/src/input.css */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this relative path `'../templates/**/*.html'` in content section

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I'm still getting the same warning and and output.css file that miss a lot of class.